# CSP Channels with native threading in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, channel, alt

I'm looking for an implementation of CSP channels on top of native threads in Python. I've seen a few libraries about but they include everything but the kitchen sink.

Specifically, I'm looking for the ability to wait for the first of a set of send and receive operations on multiple channels and either have the results of the first completed operation returned to me, or a callback invoked.

Here are a few related links for context:

- [Communicating sequential processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes)
- [Multiplex on queue.Queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456516/multiplex-on-queue-queue)
- [Go specification: Select statements](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Select_statements)

Comment: What do you mean by "native threads in Python"? Python uses GIL, and unless I'm mistaken, doesn't support native multi-threading: http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, my library python-csp has all of these. You can get the library here: https://github.com/futurecore/python-csp

Here's a simple example with channels and ALTing (also called non-deterministic selection):

```
>>> @process
... def send_msg(chan, msg):
...     chan.write(msg)
... 
>>> @process
... def alt_example(chan1, chan2):
...     alt = Alt(chan1, chan2)
...     print alt.select()
...     print alt.select()
... 
>>> c1, c2 = Channel(), Channel()
>>> Par(send_msg(c1, 'yes'), send_msg(c2, 'no'), alt_example(c1, c2)).start()
yes
no
>>>
```

I'm in the middle of refactoring the internals and cleaning things up, so keep an eye out for a release pretty soon or feel free to email me offline about it if you wish.

Comment: Nice, looks nicer than pycsp.

Comment: thanks :) Hoping for a "proper" release on PyPI in the next few weeks after this bit of refactoring.